# JS: Decrypt File with RSA

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, rsa

I have to decrypt a RSA-Encrypted file via Javascript (Node.js, to be more specific). My problem is, that it's saved as a binary file and I found only one library able to import keys from binary files: node-rsa. unfortunately I get an error when trying to use it.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './libs/rsa.js'
```

Now I checked and the file is definitely there.

I hope you can help me to either find an alternative, or to fix this error.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your application running from the directory you think it is running from?  Sometimes I have run things which were actually run in a different path.

Comment: I don't know, but `require("./libs/rsa.js")` is called from the main script (nodeRSA.js) and because it's a relative Path it should work anyways, right? I mean rsa.js IS in the folder libs.